# createFisherFaceRecognizer in Java OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement a face recognizer using the official OpenCV Java bindings (not JavaCV), however I can't seem to find the equivalent of the createFisherFaceRecognizer() method.

From my quick research, it seems as if it has not yet been implemented in Java. If this is the case, what are the workarounds / my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, known bug.

the (underlying) c++ method createFisherFaceRecognizer() returns a `Ptr<FaceRecognizer>` and the auto-generated java wrappers can't handle those Ptr types.

if you're good with jni, you could reinvent it.

javacv has a crap-api imho, but at least they got this solved manually